# How to use document.getElementByTagName() with body tag

Tags: javascript

I tried using the `document.getElementsByTagName()` method with the body tag but it didn't work.

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new");
p.appendChild(node);
var parent = document.getElementByTagName("body");
parent.appendChild(p);
```

Why does it not return results, where did I make a mistake?

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), not `getElementByTagName`

Comment: [MDN: document.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body) "The document.body property represents the <body> or <frameset> node of the current document, or null if no such element exists."

Comment: @j08691 It worked, thank you.

Comment: ```var parent = document.body``` works here!

Comment: You should also note that `getElementsByTagName()` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (an array-like object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `getElementsByTagName`, notice the plural on `Elements`.

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it returns an HTMLCollection that must then be looped through in order to call any methods or properties.

Comment: it should be document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], since it returns an array

Answer (score 2):

`document.body` will return the single element as opposed to getElementsByTagName() which will return an HTMLCollection

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new");
p.appendChild(node);
var parent = document.body;
parent.appendChild(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (however easier access to body is by `document.body` what was mention in James Allen [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562100/860099))

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

body.innerHTML += "<p>This is new</p>";
```